# How to change double quotes using "Rewriting Source Code" on single quotes for JSX in WebStorm?

Tags: ide, webstorm, jsx, jetbrains-ide

I use this:

1. Choose **Editor -> Code Style -> TypeScript/JavaScript**
2. Change: `Use 'double'
   quotes` to `Use 'single' quotes.`

But it only works for JavaScript and not work for JSX

Answer (score 0):

in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other**, try setting **Generated quote marks:** to *Single* - does it help?